# Is there an easy way to know what edition a World of Darkness sourcebook is?

Tags: world-of-darkness, history-of-gaming, product-identification, books

I've recently started getting into World of Darkness and I'm realizing there are 5 different editions of sourcebooks:

1. First edition
2. Second edition
3. Revised (3rd) edition
4. V20 (4th) edition
5. Fifth edition

Is there an easy way to know what edition a sourcebook is without having to look it up?

Like can you tell what edition it is by looking at the cover?

Comment: Is this a question that's just about Vampire, or do you want to know about the other games as well?

Comment: You guys are really helpful! I was hoping to figure out an easy way to know what edition all the books are. Vampire, werewolf, changeling, etc. It's super confusing!

Comment: Related: [How do all the World of Darkness and Chronicles of Darkness RPGs connect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140276/how-do-all-the-world-of-darkness-and-chronicles-of-darkness-rpgs-connect). And a very similar question for D&D: [How do I know which edition of Dungeons and Dragons (D&D) the books I'm looking at are for?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135571/how-do-i-know-which-edition-of-dungeons-and-dragons-dd-the-books-im-looking)

Answer (score 13):

There's 3 relatively easy ways to identify what edition our products are from:

- Print date
- Company location
- Trade dress (Logos, Fonts, Colors)

[DriveThruRPG to the rescue](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/1/White-Wolf?src=browse1) as we can see the trade dress for the various lineups in the logos of the collections. As you easily see, the general trade dress of the logos altered between editions, sometimes with only minor changes and not all books in the same series have the same Trade dress. Often the better distinguishing is the publishing years and to which system it belongs, as the version jumps happened shifted to one another.

The fans over at RPG.net have managed to [sort pretty much every book](https://index.rpg.net/display-search.phtml?key=background&value=Classic%2BWorld%2Bof%2BDarkness&sort=system) into the correct edition and hold the publication year as well as the Impressum for all of them on file, and for some, they have even print run sizes. Atop that, there are dozens of reviews of the books, making them an excellent source to sort your books and to find out if a book might be interesting for your collection.

### 1st Edition ~1991 - ~1995

Generally speaking, the first edition encompasses the **first 2 years** of a system, but this is only true for the first three systems as the latter two had more or less only about one and a half years before 2nd Edition struck. So 1st Edition Vampire was published 1991/92, Werewolf in 1992/1993, Mage in 1993/1994. The first Wraith books came late [1994](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=59&editionid=4367) and Changeling has a [1995](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=89&editionid=1039) installment when it was published as the *final installment* of the (first edition) storyteller system.

In the early days, the Logo for White wolf was also quite different from the later years, as seen in the first logo, but by 1993 swapped to the logo we know. White Wolf resides in **Stone Mountain** until 1994, 1995 shows the first books using the **Clarkston** address.

Note that the Werewolf logo is *green* on the core book but shifts to a brown-red on the supplements.

#### 1992

[image: 1992 Logo]

[image: Vampire 1st Edition cover]

#### 1993

[image: Werewolf 1st Edition Cover]
[image: Werewolf Player's Guide]
[image: Iteration X]

#### 1994

[image: 1994 from Akashic Brotherhood]

#### 1995

[image: Guildbook: Artificers]
[image: Player's kit Changeling]

#### 1996

[image: Player's Guide]

### 2nd Edition: ~1992 - ~1999

Vampire stared with the 2nd Edition still in 1992, Werewolf in 1994, Mage in 1995. Wraith came in [1996](https://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/classic/rev_1737.phtml) using a quite similar trade dress to before (see below) and Changeling followed [1997](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=89&editionid=103) but didn't alter the trade dress safe for the simple addition of "second edition" in a black edge on the front cover of the core book.

The WoD has a logo of its own now that shows up repeatedly, but not always. All of 2nd Edition has the Company listed under the same address in **Clarkston**, a suburb of Atlanta. Note that there are some rare 1997 prints using Atlanta as the city name - [T.J.L.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/22138/t-j-l) owns a [1997 first-print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJXjS.jpg) of Changeling 2nd Edition like this, while his 2000 reprint shows Clarkston.

Vampire's *subline* has a different font - no longer rounded but a Serif style reminiscent of Times New Roman but the main line is exactly as 1st edition. Werewolf has a red font between bars now and has a totally different font that is no longer italic and more erratic (claw-made) in style but **with** a yellow outline. The Mage logo is dimmed in color or (later) starting to go without a cartouche, but the title is not decorated otherwise. The Wraith Logo no longer fades out at the lower end but has a solid outline.

Changeling has no easy to spot alterations in trade dress, so I suggest to rely on RPG.net and the location of the company to identify the edition here.

#### 1997

[image: WoD Logo]
[image: Mage Logo]
[image: Guildbook Pardoners & Puppeters]
[image: Isle of the Mighty showing Changling, WoD and Mage Logo, the latter without cartouche]
[image: Changeling 2nd Edition 1997 print with Atlanta Address][image: 1997 Company Logo in Sorcerer]

#### 1998

[image: Logo on "Hong Kong"/Year of the Lotus][image: Accompanying Company Logo & Adress 1998]
[image: Werewolf Player's Guide]
[image: Wraith, Tokyo]

### Revised Edition: ~1998 - 2004 ; 2013

The Revised Edition started **1998** with Vampire, but in the first year might still use 2nd edition trade dress (see abo, 2000 with Werewolf and for Mage in **2001**. Wraith was killed off and replaced by *Demon: The Fallen* and *Hunter: The Reckoning* as well as *Mummy: The Resurrection*. *Kindred of the East* was using the Revised rules set too but is a bolt-on to Vampire.

Changeling doesn't seem to have been published with Revised Edition rules but for a tie in into *Time of Judgement*.

No book belonging to Revised Edition was **printed** after **2004**.

*However* there are some pdf/print on demand only releases of Revised books that were made as hype for the, then upcoming, Mage 20th anniversary edition in the shape of the **2013** Technocracy books, which also featuried Onyx Path Publishing on the covers and inside, but use otherwise the revised trade dress and ruleset.

The company moved from **Clarkston** back to **Stone Mountain** between 2001 and 2003, and altered the address in Stone Mountain by 2004.

Vampire has a totally different font for the logo, the subline being integrated into it with a font similar to the title. Werewolf has lost the yellow outline around the brand logo. Mage lost the Cartouche around the Logo and instead features decorations in the lower half of the text.

#### 2001

[image: Logo 2001 from Witches & Pagans][image: Imprint Logo, Witches & Pagans]
[image: Celestial Chorus]

#### 2003

[image: Demon The Fallen Player Guide]
[image]
[image: Werewolf revised core book]

#### 2004

[image: 2004 White Wolf] [image: 2004 WoD] [image: 2004 inner cover Logo/Company Adress]

[image: Vampire, 2004]

#### 2013 (*late* PDF/POD-Only releases)

[image: Progenitors Revised]

### 20th Anniversary Editions: 2011 - Partially ended

The 20th Anniversary Edition uses a style reminiscent of the 1st and 2nd editions, however, all books have print dates starting **2011** - anything after is most likely this. The amount of books per splat is relatively small, but each one is very thick. Vampire and Werewolf are *complete* as of summer 2020, Vampire having started their 5th edition while Werewolf's 5th edition is still in the works. The other splats have some books still coming out, Wraith 20 started publishing in 2018 and might still have some in the making. A complete listing of the books can be got from DTRPG using the appropriate system tags, for example for [V20](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/4261/Onyx-Path-Publishing/subcategory/8329_20632/Vampire-20th-Anniversary), [V20:DA](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/4261/Onyx-Path-Publishing/subcategory/8329_20643/V20-Dark-Ages), [W20](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/4261/Onyx-Path-Publishing/subcategory/8329_20631/Werewolf-20th-Anniversary), [M20](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/4261/Onyx-Path-Publishing/subcategory/8329_20645/Mage-20th-Anniversary), [Wr20](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/4261/Onyx-Path-Publishing/subcategory/8329_30845/Wraith-20th-Anniversary), [C20](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/4261/Onyx-Path-Publishing/subcategory/8329_28737/Changeling-20th-Anniversary).

The White Wolf Logo is most often found *without* text, and there's an accompanying Onyx Path Logo always. The Trade dress makes it usually VERY clear that it is the 20th Anniversary version - usually with a line above the title.

[image]

[image][image][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### 5th Edition: 2018 ongoing

At the time of this writing (July 2020), the 5th edition had been mostly exclusive to Vampire. It is published since August 2018. The Trade dress has a small, red circle with the white inscription WoD in the lower corner with no surrounding frame as a replacement for the old WoD logo.

[image: Vampire 5 WoD Cartouche][image: Hunter WoD Cartouche]

The lettering of the system is all capitals Vampire between two lines, using Friz Quadrata—again a font not used previously. The Masquerade in all capitals below the lower line, this time in the same font as the title. With the 2nd Printing, there is a Stiletto Ankh as Q.

Do note, that the first core book was published with a 2019 copyright notice by Modiphiüs, their branding next to a White-Wolf mark. The White Wolf mark was replaced with the Paradox logo in 2020. However, *some* credit lines on the cover page from the same year are pure text, only listing White Wolf.

#### 2019

[image: V5 2nd Printing Cor Book Cover (2019)]
[image: V5 Core book credit line, 2nd Printing, "2019"]

#### 2020

[image: V5 Fall of London Cover Cartouche, "2020"]
[image: V5 Fall of London Back Cartouche, "2020"]
[image: V5 The Chicago Folios credit line "2020"]

Werewolf 5th Edition originally started development licensed to hunters entertainment in around 2018 and [was originally planned to release 2021](https://www.huntersentertainment.com/single-post/werewolf-the-apocalypse), but this fell through.

In late 2020 [Paradox consolidated all WoD TTRPG development to Renegade Game Studio](https://www.paradoxinteractive.com/media/press-releases/press-release/world-of-darkness-names-renegade-game-studios-publishing-partner-for-its-catalogue-of-tabletop-rpgs). All subsequent releases now carry the Renegade Game Studio and Paradox Entertainment marks. The credit line on the inside though might or might not show Renegade Game Studio though, as Cults of the Blood Gods shows:

[image: V5 Cults of the Blood Gods, credit line]

The accompanying [website for all the World of Darkness products](https://www.worldofdarkness.com/products/tabletop-games) shows the already known trade dress for Vampire, as well as glimpses of the Werewolf, and Hunter logos. The site there listed in August 2022 the Werewolf core rulebook as "coming". Between [October 2021](https://youtu.be/2L9Cj3VMHzw) and then, no statements about the development of Werewolf had been made, which was preceded by about a year of occasional statements.

On the flip side, *Hunter: The Reckoning 5th edition* was first announced in [October 2021](https://youtu.be/O3YQiAr8V20) and released in the US in mid-2022. It is all in disturbed Stencil letters. The Backside of the Hunter book denominates both Paradox and Renegade Games Studio.

The first release for Werewolf 5th Edition happened in [August 2023](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Werewolf:_The_Apocalypse_5th_Edition). The new Werewolf Logo consists of the Claw-like W from the 2nd edition to the 20th Anniversary edition, but military stencils for the rest of the word, disturbed at the OL with claw marks. It is virtually the same logo as the computer games released in [October 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werewolf:_The_Apocalypse_%E2%80%93_Heart_of_the_Forest) and [February 2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werewolf:_The_Apocalypse_%E2%80%93_Earthblood).

[image: 2022 trade dress for logos]
[image: Back-Cartouche from Hunter]

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie update!

Answer (score 6):

The typeface of the trade dress changes from edition to edition, so one way to tell is by looking at the letters used at the bottom of the cover in the line that says "A [x] Sourcebook for [y]" or the like. As an example, in *Mage*, the Abbess font is used for First and Second edition books, and Visitation is used for Revised.

Answer (score 5):

2nd page of most WoD books > date of printing vs date of edition releases.

or on WW wiki:

https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_World_of_Darkness_sourcebooks

As to the "by looking at cover" question:

In combination with wiki, a google image search of the "ibsn" listed on wiki for cover of book in question

This [LINK](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Chronicles_of_Darkness) is the CoD or "Chronicle of Darkness", It lists every date of publication/edition & would be the source I would quot, So I feel linking it is more direct

Note that "Paradox Interactive" now owns the "WoD" (2015 to date of this edit) with stated plans to (re)release rules under "One World of Darkness" unifying rule set.

> Following the purchase of White Wolf and the World of Darkness by
>   Paradox Interactive in 2015, Paradox unveiled their plans to create
>   "**One World of Darkness**", unifying all fans and versions of the World
>   of Darkness under one umbrella. In December of that year, the "new"
>   World of Darkness saw its name changed to "Chronicles of Darkness" to
>   more fully distinguish it from the "classic" World of Darkness. Onyx
>   Path will continue to produce new material for the CoD setting
>   (including the aforementioned **second editions** and new game lines), and
>   Paradox's reestablished White Wolf studio will develop new editions of
>   the classic World of Darkness setting in-house.

I take this to mean 2nd edition is the superseding-ly "Current" rule set for the WoD (now CoD), until a "unified system release"

Below is the most current IN PRINT release I could locate:

> The Huntsmen Chronicle - The **second edition** of Changeling: The Lost. A
>   game of bittersweet truth. Released in January 2019.

Comment: Do you know what dates are the cut offs per edition? If you can provide a nice breakdown I'll chose yours as the answer. Also what's an ibsn? It'd be nice if you provided more details on what you mean by things. Like, when you say "date of printing" do you mean, copyright? Can you provide an example of how you would look up a book using the wiki and google image search?

Comment: @rotaercz ISBN (International Standard Book Number) is the "bar code" or "serial code". check both these as examples: both list PRINTING DATE, and EDITION NUMBER
Here is an example for the main vampire book (https://m.directtextbook.com/isbn/9781565042490) Here is "monkeywrench pentex" (https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30209587862&searchurl=an%3DBRAD%2BFREEMAN%26sortby%3D17)

Comment: @rotaercz thats the most current info I could locate, I havent played WoD in a VERY long time