# How do I identify the edition of a Shadowrun book?

Tags: product-identification, books, shadowrun

There is guidance on how trade dress of [WoD](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164886/is-there-an-easy-way-to-know-what-edition-a-world-of-darkness-sourcebook-is) and [D&D](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135571/how-do-i-know-which-edition-of-dungeons-and-dragons-dd-the-books-im-looking) changes over the editions, but how do you do that in Shadowrun?

How can I tell what edition a particular Shadowrun book is for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Check the Back

Unlike some publishers, where you frequently have to examine trade dress and other elements of the book's design, Shadowrun's publishers - FASA, FanPro, and Catalyst - have been good about including the edition's name in print on the back cover. Sometimes it's a standalone line "For use with Shadowrun [Edition]", while other times it's in the body text of the back cover blurb itself. They even call out when a book straddled multiple editions, most often seen during the transition from SR1 to SR2:

[image: Imago - Back Cover, Showing Editions]

This is not to say that they don't have trade dress that they change up with each edition, but reading the text on the back doesn't require remembering which color scheme is which edition.

Comment: Worth mentioning that some books say: "Compatible with all editions of Shadowrun".

Comment: @ShadowKras I think those books speak for themselves. :)